# "no" input function does not work in while loop Java

Tags: java

- The program should validate user input.
- Game should ask the user to play again and continue if yes and stop if no.
- Once the user stops playing, program should print the total number of wins for the computer and for the user.
  When I type "no", it prints "Type 1 for rock,..." instead of printing out the score. Here is my code below:

  ```
    import java.util.*;
    public class rockPaperScissors
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Do you want to play a round of rock, paper, scissors? Type yes or no.");
        String YoN = input.nextLine();//yes or no repsonse
        int Uwin = 0;//user win count
        int Cwin = 0;//computer win count
        int tie = 0;//tie count
        if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            while (!YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
            {
                System.out.println("Type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors.");
                Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
                int choice = console.nextInt();
                while (choice < 1 || choice > 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please type 1, 2, or 3.");
                    choice = console.nextInt();
                }
                Random r = new Random();
                int comp = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
                if (comp == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer chose rock.");
                }
                if (comp == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer chose paper.");
                }
                 if (comp == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer chose scissors.");
                }
                if ((choice == 3 && comp == 1) || (choice == 2 && comp == 3) || (choice == 1 && comp == 2))
                {
                    Cwin++;
                }
                else if ((choice == 2 && comp == 1) || (choice == 3 && comp == 2) || (choice == 1 && comp == 3))
                {
                    Uwin++;
                }
                else
                {
                    tie++;
                }
                System.out.println("Computer wins: " + Cwin + "\nYour wins: " + Uwin + "\nTies: " + tie);
                System.out.println("\n\nDo you want to play a round of rock, paper, scissors?");
                YoN = console.nextLine();
                console.nextLine();
                if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Computer wins: " + Cwin + "\nYour wins: " + Uwin + "\nTies: " + tie);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please type yes or no.");
            YoN = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: Have you stepped through your program with the debugger? It looks as though some code you want outside your loop is inside it, and you never update `YoN` after the first time.

Comment: after asking user if they want to play again, replace `choice = console.nextInt();` with  `YoN = input.nextLine();`

Comment: Also you will have problems with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Answer (score 1):

This works. I have changed the line `YoN = console.nextLine();` to `YoN = input.nextLine();`.

```
  import java.util.*;
  public class rockPaperScissors
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Do you want to play a round of rock, paper, scissors? Type yes or no.");
      String YoN = input.nextLine();//yes or no repsonse
      int Uwin = 0;//user win count
      int Cwin = 0;//computer win count
      int tie = 0;//tie count
      if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
      {
          while (!YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
          {
              System.out.println("Type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors.");
              Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
              int choice = console.nextInt();
              while (choice < 1 || choice > 3)
              {
                  System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please type 1, 2, or 3.");
                  choice = console.nextInt();
              }
              Random r = new Random();
              int comp = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
              if (comp == 1)
              {
                  System.out.println("Computer chose rock.");
              }
              if (comp == 2)
              {
                  System.out.println("Computer chose paper.");
              }
               if (comp == 3)
              {
                  System.out.println("Computer chose scissors.");
              }
              if ((choice == 3 && comp == 1) || (choice == 2 && comp == 3) || (choice == 1 && comp == 2))
              {
                  Cwin++;
              }
              else if ((choice == 2 && comp == 1) || (choice == 3 && comp == 2) || (choice == 1 && comp == 3))
              {
                  Uwin++;
              }
              else
              {
                  tie++;
              }
              System.out.println("Computer wins: " + Cwin + "\nYour wins: " + Uwin + "\nTies: " + tie);
              System.out.println("\n\nDo you want to play a round of rock, paper, scissors?");
              YoN = input.nextLine();
              //console.nextLine();
              if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
              {
                  System.out.println("Computer wins: " + Cwin + "\nYour wins: " + Uwin + "\nTies: " + tie);
              }
          }
      }
      else if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
      {
          System.out.println("Thank you!");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please type yes or no.");
          YoN = input.nextLine();
      }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
public class RockPaperScissors {

    private static final String YES = "yes";
    private static final String NO = "no";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();

        Map<Player, Integer> winners = new EnumMap<>(Player.class);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to play a round of rock, paper, scissors?");
            System.out.format("Type '%s' or '%s': ", YES, NO);
            String str = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            if (YES.equals(str)) {
                Player winner = playGameAndGetWinner(scan, random);
                winners.put(winner, winners.getOrDefault(winner, 0) + 1);

                System.out.print("Game result is: ");

                if (winner == Player.DRAW)
                    System.out.println(Player.DRAW.title);
                else
                    System.out.format("winner is %s.\n", winner.title);

                printStatistics(winners);
            } else if (NO.equals(str)) {
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
                break;
            } else
                System.err.println("Invalid entry. Please type 'yes' or 'no'.");
        }
    }

    private static Player playGameAndGetWinner(Scanner scan, Random random) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.format("Type '%d' for %s, '%d' for %s, and '%d' for %s: ",
                    Choice.ROCK.id, Choice.ROCK.title,
                    Choice.PAPER.id, Choice.PAPER.title,
                    Choice.SCISSORS.id, Choice.SCISSORS.title);
            Choice userChoice = Choice.parseId(scan.nextInt());

            if (userChoice == Choice.NULL) {
                System.err.format("Invalid %s choose.\n", Player.USER.title);
                continue;
            }

            Choice botChoice = Choice.random(random);

            if (botChoice == Choice.NULL) {
                System.err.format("Invalid %s choose.\n", Player.BOT.title);
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.format("'%s' choose '%s'\n", Player.USER.title, userChoice.title);
            System.out.format("'%s' choose '%s'\n", Player.BOT.title, botChoice.title);
            System.out.println();
            scan.nextLine();

            return Choice.getWinner(userChoice, botChoice);
        }
    }

    private static void printStatistics(Map<Player, Integer> winners) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Overall statistics.");

        Arrays.stream(Player.values()).forEach(player ->
                System.out.format("'%s' win count: %d\n",
                        player.title, winners.getOrDefault(player, 0)));
        System.out.println();
    }

    private enum Choice {
        NULL(0, "<null>") {
            @Override
            public Player winner(Choice botChoice) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        },
        ROCK(1, "rock") {
            @Override
            public Player winner(Choice botChoice) {
                return botChoice == SCISSORS ? Player.USER : Player.BOT;
            }
        },
        PAPER(2, "paper") {
            @Override
            public Player winner(Choice botChoice) {
                return botChoice == ROCK ? Player.USER : Player.BOT;
            }
        },
        SCISSORS(3, "scissors") {
            @Override
            public Player winner(Choice botChoice) {
                return botChoice == PAPER ? Player.USER : Player.BOT;
            }
        };

        private final int id;
        private final String title;

        Choice(int id, String title) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public static Player getWinner(Choice userChoice, Choice botChoice) {
            if (userChoice == null || botChoice == null)
                throw new RuntimeException();
            if (userChoice == NULL || botChoice == NULL)
                throw new RuntimeException();
            if (userChoice == botChoice)
                return Player.DRAW;
            return userChoice.winner(botChoice);
        }

        protected abstract Player winner(Choice botChoice);

        public static Choice random(Random random) {
            return parseId(random.nextInt(SCISSORS.id) + 1);
        }

        public static Choice parseId(int id) {
            for (Choice choice : values())
                if (choice != NULL && choice.id == id)
                    return choice;
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    private enum Player {
        DRAW("draw"),
        USER("user"),
        BOT("bot");

        private final String title;

        Player(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }

}
```